# What is the proper event for input="text"

Tags: ajax, jquery, events

I have an input field which is `start_time` and `end_time` and these fields are formatted with the data-format  `HH:mm:ss PP`.

What I want to do is when the user is done entering the data, then I'll do some AJAX to calculate the time.

But, I'm a little bit confused because I don't know what is the proper event for the input fields. I tried `keydown`,`keyup`,`focus` but still doesn't work.

Here is the input field `start_time`:

```
    <div class='input-append' id='datetimepicker2'>
        <input data-format='HH:mm:ss PP' type='text' name="start_time" id="start_time" value="<?php echo set_value('start_time')?>"/>
        <span class='add-on'>
          <i data-date-icon='icon-calendar' data-time-icon='icon-time'>
          </i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
          language: 'en',
          pick12HourFormat: true,
          pickDate: false
        });
      });
    </script>
```

And for the `end_time`:

```
    <div class='input-append' id='datetimepicker3'>
                <input data-format='HH:mm:ss PP' type='text' name="end_time" id="end_time" value="<?php echo set_value('end_time') ?>"/>
                <span class='add-on'>
                  <i data-date-icon='icon-calendar' data-time-icon='icon-time'>
                  </i>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div><script type='text/javascript'>
              $(function() {
                $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                  language: 'en',
                  pick12HourFormat: true,
                  pickDate: false

                });
              });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onblur), sothat when the user finish entering the data in input field and gets focus out of the field the event gets triggered.

**edited according to comments below**

I guess you are using [bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) in your code. If not so, please mention the datpicker or the js library that you are using.

In the case of bootstrap date picker yu can look at the [changedate](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker#changedate) event for your task which will get triggered each time a change is made on your datepicker value. Also you can check the changeYear && changeMonth events also which are available.

here is a [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/UTGp9/) using the code you provided which will trigger an alert whenever a change is made on the corresponding datepicker. You can replace it with whatever code you want to execute on change.

sample code snippet

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      language: 'en',
      pick12HourFormat: true,
      pickDate: false
}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
    alert("first one changed"); // replace with your code block
});;
```

Comment: doesn't work in my case sir. because i have an icon or javascripted timepicker and the focus in input field does not appear on it

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza: which date picker are you using? mention the code or js framework in your question.

Comment: i used tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ for my timepicker UI